# How to control an 12V 2A Car lamp using relay or MOSFET in Arduino

Tags: relay, mosfet

I am working with the project controlling an 25W 12V Car lamp. I have a 12V car battery. I want to control it with the Arduino using a relay or MOSFET.

Any suggestion for my project would be appreciated.

Comment: You do it the same way as any other kind of light control. "Car" makes no difference.

Comment: But arduino output draws only minimum amount of current for 25W 12v lamp the current rating should 1.75A how to boost up the current to make the lamp ON

Comment: You already answered that in your question - use a MOSFET or a relay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [RFP30N06LE](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/RFP30N06LE.pdf) mosfet. It can support up to 60V 30A

Here is a wiring schema
[image]

Comment: and one more doubt....is ground can be common for different current rated loads....Example i am using 12v car battery in that load side i have 5W and 21W lamps can i connect ground of these 2 common....because i am using ground switching for output....supply is directly given to all lamps...

Comment: Ground have to be common. It won't works if they are not connected each other